# I want to add dummy data in a table in my tkinter project

Tags: python, tkinter, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, datatable

tkinter code

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# making the window
root = Tk()
# initiating the table
table = ttk.Treeview(root)
table['columns'] = ('Name', 'Price', 'Dummy')
table.column('#0', width=0, stretch=NO)
table.column('Name', anchor=CENTER, width=250)
table.column('Price', anchor=CENTER, width=150)
table.column('Dummy', anchor=CENTER, width=150)
# table.heading('#0', text='', anchor=CENTER)
table.heading('Name', text='Name', anchor=CENTER)
table.heading('Price', text='Price', anchor=CENTER)
table.heading('Dummy', text='Stock: ', anchor=CENTER)

drink_price = {}

index = 0

table.pack()
```

start of web scraper

```
webpage = requests.get(
  "https://www.spinneyslebanon.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=pepsi")

soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage.content, "html.parser")

title = soup.find_all("a", "product-item-link")
price = soup.find_all("span", class_="price")

titles = []
prices = []
for index, tp in enumerate(zip(title, price)):
    if index >= 10:
        break
    drink_price[tp[0].get_text(strip=True)] = tp[1].get_text(strip=True)

print(titles)
print(prices)
```

end of web scraper

```
for i in drink_price:
    price = drink_price.get(i)
    table.insert(parent='', index=index, iid=index, text='', values=(i, price))
    index += 1

    root.mainloop()
```

output[image]

I want any dummy data under the stock: part

Name and Price are all legit data from a web scraper as shown in the code
the dummy data can be any thing but most preferably numbers like 97, 33,...

Comment: Does this work: `table.insert(parent='', index=index, iid=index, text='', values=(i, price, random.randint(0, 100)))` ? You need to also `import random`

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts. You don't own them: by posting you [licensed this content under a Creative Commons license](https://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing). You cannot revoke that license. The spirit of Stack Overflow is that each user's contributions will help future users with similar problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really know `Tkinter`, but one option would be to insert a random number using the [`randint`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randint) method available from the built-in [`random`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html) module:

```
import random
[...]

table.insert(parent='', index=index, iid=index, text='', values=(i, price, random.randint(0, 100)))
```

EDIT:
If you want to randomly insert a blank value or a digit, you can use [`random.choice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice) to pick either an empty string `""` or a number:

```
table.insert(parent='', index=index, iid=index, text='', values=(i, price, random.choice(["", random.randint(0, 100)])))
```